# NDI ( Network Device Interface ) with Python

Tags: python, c++, ndi

I want to program a python script that list the all available NDI sources.
Over a LAN connection finds NDI sources ,receives data from them and updates the data on status change.
The data to be read is:
NDI source name
Source IP Address
Source Tally status (tally on preview and on program)
The data should be printed on screen in the following manner:
and so on...

Whenever there is a change in the received data, a new line with the updated status should be printed immediately.

NDI (network device interface) is a video/audio over ip distribution protocol and it's royalty-free, the SDK is distributable as such.

The goal for this program is to just plug in a LAN network and collect the data.
can anyone help me with this, how i can interact with an SDK using python?
Please I need help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the guidelines on how to post question. As a general rule, it is not ok to expect the community to solve a problem without showing any personal effort to do so. Please post your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

There's an NDI Python wrapper on GitHub:

https://github.com/buresu/ndi-python

As far as I'm aware it can do most things the original SDK can - maybe with a bit of tweaking to the original SDK example scripts. There are four example scripts provided in the release anyway. I'd suggest:

1. Installing the SDK from NewTek
2. Building the NDI wrapper
3. Follow the SDK documentation as to what you can get out of it
4. Building your code using the examples to help you.

It has worked well for a research project I'm doing so I hope this helps you too.